# SQL query error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, data-conversion

I search about the error, but I only find different answers that didn't work for me.

I have this query, in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @column_name varchar (25),
@data_column int,
@table_name varchar (25)

DECLARE @mySql nvarchar (MAX)

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @column_name = 'Excellent'
SET @table_name = 'CSAT'
SET @data_column = 10

SET @mySql = 'INSERT INTO '+@table_name+'('+@column_name+') VALUES('+@data_column+')'
EXEC (@mySql)
```

When I execute it, it shows me this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'INSERT INTO CSAT(Excellent) VALUES(' to data type int.

All the columns are Int and allow nulls.

I have to make a conversion or something? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@data_column is an int, so you need to convert it to varchar because you are building a string.

```
SET @mySql = 'INSERT INTO '+@table_name+'('+@column_name+') 
              VALUES('+ Convert(Varchar(10), @data_column)+')'
```

When sql server encounters an expression that mixes strings and int, it attempts to convert the string to an int (instead of the the other way around).  This is documented here: [SQL Server Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

Comment: If you check your column_name and table_name against the tables and columns in your database, there would be no vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

add some space like this

```
SET @mySql = 'INSERT INTO '+@table_name+' ('+convert(varchar(50),@column_name)+') VALUES('+@data_column+')'
```

Answer (score 0):

The sql is trying to make a sum of your string on line:

```
SET @mySql = 'INSERT INTO '+@table_name+'('+@column_name+') VALUES('+@data_column+')'
```

Change the @data_column parameter from int to varchar or use a CONCAT function to create your SQL command:

```
SET @mySql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@table_name,' (',@column_name,') VALUES(',@data_column,')')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Parametrised Query to do this, Also use appropriate datatype for object names...

something like this....

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @column_name  SYSNAME
       ,@data_column  INT
       ,@table_name   SYSNAME
       ,@mySql        NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @column_name = 'Excellent'
SET @table_name = 'CSAT'
SET @data_column = 10

SET @mySql = N' INSERT INTO '+ QUOTENAME(@table_name) 
          +  N' ('+ QUOTENAME(@column_name) +') '
          +  N' VALUES( @data_column )'


Exec sp_executesql @mySql
                  ,N'@data_column INT'
                  ,@data_column
```